# Curl in drupal 7 fails

Tags: php, curl, drupal-7

I am trying to post content to a Drupal 7 site. I don't have administrator privileges so I have to use a module to upload. I am trying to use PHP with curl but it's quite messy:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
define("COOKIE_FILE", "/tmp/cookie.txt");
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
$crl = curl_init();
$http_headers = array(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36', // Any User-Agent will do here
);
$url = "http://mysite.gr/drupal/user/login";

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$postdata=array(
    "name" => "user",
    "pass" => "pass",
    "form_id" => "user_login",
    "op" => "Submit",
);

// Tell curl we're going to send $postdata as the POST data
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

$result=curl_exec($crl);
$headers = curl_getinfo($crl);
echo curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
//$file = fopen("/tmp/cookie.txt", 'r');
//fread($file, 100000000);

$crl = curl_init();
$url = "http://mysite.gr/drupal/node/add/simple";

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");

curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$postdata = array(
    "title" => "dokimastiki anartisi",
    "changed" => "",
    "form_id" => "simple_node_form",
    "body[und][0][value]" => "hhhhhhh",
    "form_id" => "simple-node-form",
    "op" => "Save",
);

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

$result=curl_exec($crl);
$headers = curl_getinfo($crl);
echo curl_exec($crl);
?>
```

It seems that the login succeeds. When it is time to upload I get these errors. The problem is most likely with how the session cookie is stored or the user agent headers. I've searched for hours with no luck for a solution:

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 12:49:11 GMT Server: Apache X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.18 Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Content-Language: en X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org) Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 X-Backend-Server: standard_backend/web10.hosting.stackcp.net

Anyone knows what I should do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? if you want use drupal like an api you should use Services module https://www.drupal.org/project/services

Comment: I want to upload content like articles and images to a certain content type. Using a module is not an option cause I dont have an admin acount.I can use curl to login as poweruser but when I try to use the content type page it's unsuccessfull.

Comment: It's a good way to use drupal .. you're not able to do that , use a developped api with Service module able to you to do everything safely . You are  "hacking" wth your method , it's a very bad way for security